# Proving $\frac{x^n}{n!} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove the question in the title. Was wondering if someone could look over it, add any alternative proofs for my own knowledge, cheers. Also, I am allowed to use this fact in the proof, which I do:

> If $|a| < 1$ then $a^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Let $N > 2x$, then:

$\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right| = \left|\frac{x^N}{N!} \left( \frac{x}{N+1} \frac{x}{N+2} \dots \frac{x}{n}  \right)\right|$

Note that the terms in parentheses are all less than $\frac{1}{2}$ because for some integer $c$, $\frac{x}{N + c} < \frac{x}{N} < \frac{1}{2}$. Then we have,

$\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right| < \left|\frac{x^N}{N!}\right|  \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{n - N}$

Clearly, $\left|\frac{x^N}{N!}\right|  \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{n - N}$ converges to $0$ using the fact stated at the beginning of the proof. Then by the sandwich theorem (squeeze theorem),  $\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Here's a stupid way to do it: 

$\exp x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is absolutely convergent for all $x$, hence we must have $\frac{x^n}{n!} \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$.

Comment: This is the more elementary proof that I know of this. Good job!

Comment: Your proof is just fine, although I would avoid $\times$ (other than for cross product of vectors) in advanced mathematics :)

Comment: You might want to use \cdot instead. :) ... Also, to be super pedantic, you should have $|x|$ in your various inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

We could just prove that the sum $$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
converges, which would automatically prove the result required. (In fact, this would converge to $e^x$). There are many ways of showing this fact (Taylor Series Expansion, etc). We then use the theorem that any infinite converging positive sum must have the terms tending to 0

Comment: Hm, this is another nice approach. Thank you!

Comment: I'm concerned this might end up being circular. That is, that the proof that the series converges relies on the fact that its terms go to zero.

Comment: @eyeballfrog There is no circular reasoning. You can derive the series expansion by expanding $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\tfrac{x}{n})^n$, which may in turn be shown to converge as $\{(1+\tfrac{x}{n})^n\}$ is a monotonically increasing bounded sequence.

Comment: Or apply the ratio test.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I believe it is more incomplete than outright circular. Although, the op seems to know that as he said "we could just prove..." but offered no such proof.

Comment: This is definitely not circular.  In fact it gives a sometimes useful  test for convergence of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive real numbers: if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof looks fine. For your information, note that $2$ can be replaced with any real greater than $1$.

Comment: Yes of course, I chose 2 for convenience but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative proof. We know that
$$
n! = \Gamma(n+1) = \int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t}dt
$$
Assuming for the moment $x > 0$,
$$
\frac{n!}{x^n} = \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{t}{x}\right)^ne^{-t}dt = x\int_0^\infty u^n e^{-xu}du > x\int_2^\infty u^ne^{-xu}du > x\int_2^\infty 2^n e^{-xu} du = 2^ne^{-2x}
$$
Thus, $0 < x^n/n! < 2^{-n}e^{2x}$, which gives the desired result from the squeeze theorem.